# Картинка выходит за рамки блока (HTML, CSS)

Tags: html, css

Попросили помочь с сайтом, не могу разобраться в чём проблема. Есть первая фоновая картинка на сайте [vellmaxx.com](https://vellmaxx.com) и она не подходит под размер блока. До её замены всё было норм, а сейчас даже старое фото не подходит, хотя кроме пути к файлу ничего не менялось. Принудительное изменение размера не подошло, применение стилей и игнорирование css тоже. Подскажите, в чём тут загвоздка?

Comment: вы бы привели картинку как это выглядит или в чем проблема - зашел на сайт - вроде все ок

Comment: @Zhihar к сожалению не вижу как добавить скрин в коммент. Суть в чём, если изменить масштаб, явно видно что первая картинка цепляется за левый угол и не адаптируется по размеру как остальные элементы сайта. При маленьком разрешении, соответственно, например с телефона, картинка очень большая и можно слайдить в бок

Comment: там у картинки прописана ширина 100%, но родительский блок имеет фиксированно заданную ширину. Может в процессе редактирования задели ширину и она прописалась туда или вроде того. Родительскому нужно задать ширину 100%.

Answer (score 1):

есть я правильно понял вопрос, то надо

1. добавить блоку `img` свойства `max-width: 100%` ну или сколько оно там должно быть с учётом отступов

https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=faq&file=css-auto-resize-an-image-proportionally

2. чтобы картинка корректно входила в некоторый блок можно использовать стиль `object-fit`

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

3. как вариант - картинку можно сделать задним фоном блока и применить стиль `background-size`

http://htmlbook.ru/css/background-size